# c++ mysql stored procedure error code 1327

Tags: c++, mysql

I have this table

```
create table utilizator(
      utilizatorId bigint not null auto_increment primary key,
      loghin varchar(500),
      password varchar(50) not null,
      tip bigint not null,
      persoanaId bigint not null,
      evenimentId bigint not null);
```

and this code in c++

```
 string vU="demo",vP="1234";
 Driver * vDriver = get_driver_instance();
 auto_ptr< Connection > vCon(vDriver->connect(getHost(),getUser() , getPassword() ));
 vCon->setSchema(getDB());
 auto_ptr< Statement > vStmt(vCon->createStatement());

 vStmt->execute("DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS fLoghin");   
 vStmt->execute("CREATE PROCEDURE fLoghin(in pUser varchar(200),in pPass varchar(200),out pUId int,out pTip int,out pEId int) BEGIN   select utilizatorId into pUId ,tip into pTip,evenimentId into pEId from utilizator where loghin=pUser and password=pPass ;  END ; ");
 vStmt->execute("CALL fLoghin("+vU+","+vP+", @out1,@out2,@out3)");

 auto_ptr<ResultSet > res(vStmt->executeQuery("SELECT @out1,@out2,@out3 AS _reply"));
    while (res->next())
      cout << "... @output = " << res->getString("_reply") << endl;
```

At line  **vStmt->execute("CREATE PROCEDURE ...**  I get this error

```
 ERR: Undeclared variable: tip (MySQL error code: 1327, SQLState: 42000 )
```

Comment: what kind of query is that: `select utilizatorId into pUId ,tip into pTip,evenimentId into pEId from utilizator`

Comment: you have right if i try `vStmt->execute("DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS fLoghin");   
    vStmt->execute("CREATE PROCEDURE fLoghin(in pUser varchar(200),in pPass varchar(200),out pUId int,out pTip int,out pEId int) BEGIN   select utilizatorId  from utilizator where loghin=pUser and password=pPass into pUId;  END ; "); ` this is work , but i can't do this with one select?

Comment: What should the select query do?

Comment: is a stored procedure who return in 3 parameter 3 variable from table utilizator  `select utilizatorId,tip,evenimentId from utilizatore where ... ` utilizatorId  to pUId, tip to pTip and evenimentId to pEId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
CREATE PROCEDURE fLoghin(in pUser varchar(200),
                         in pPass varchar(200),
                         out pUId int,
                         out pTip int,
                         out pEId int) 
BEGIN   
    select pUId = utilizatorId, pTip = tip, pEId = evenimentId
    from utilizator 
    where loghin=pUser and password=pPass ;  
END ;
```

I can't verify right now. Maybe you need to put a `@` in front of your variables like

```
@PUId = utilizatorId ...
```